# How to allow FTP traffic in iptables without opening all ports higher then 1024 to tcp connection?

Tags: ftp, iptables, vsftpd

The best answer I found for allowing FTP traffic with iptables is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93555/318849)

Following that I used the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1024: --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

But it opens all the ports greater or equal to 1024 to tcp connection, Which is not great in terms of firewall rules.

All these ports are open in order to allow FTP passive inbound traffic.

So I want to know how is it possible to install a `vsftpd` server and keeping a tighter firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to limit the port range `vsftpd` uses for passive inbound traffic by adding the following lines to my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
pasv_min_port=22200
pasv_max_port=22210
```

After limiting the passive inbound traffic port ranges I used the following iptable rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW, -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22200:22210 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can/should have a `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule that is not limited to specific port (range):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I will update question and answer

Comment: The `RELATED` part of the rule should cover the pasv port *dynamically*.